# jsconfig.json paths not working when importing function

Tags: javascript

I tried to learn implement absolute path, and I create project with structure like this

```
├── helper
│   ├── api
│   │   ├── fire.js
│   ├── support
│   │   ├── help.js
├── project
│   └── main
│   │   ├──  subtile
│   │   │    ├────── index.js
```

jsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "baseUrl": ".",
      "paths": {
        "@/helper/*": ["helper/*"]
      }
    }
}
```

[image]

But when I tried to run the project i got error `Uncaught Error Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package '@/helper' imported from`

Comment: Please provide actual code the reproduces your issue not just a picture.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss thanks for your suggestion, I  already update it

Comment: I find [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig#_jsconfig-options) helps

Comment: what happens inside fire.js?

Answer (score 0):

jscofig is only the config of the editor in the development environment, the import path will not change when nodejs is running.

you can use [https://github.com/ilearnio/module-alias](https://solve%20it) solve it